# Overloading assignment operator: different datatypes - impossible?

Tags: c++, class, operators, overloading, variable-assignment

I am trying to make something that is probably impossible to do with operator overloading. I am particularly interested in overloading assignment operator, which would receive **another data type** value as its right hand value. It should look like this:

```
MyClass myclass = "hello world";    <--- Wrong?

MyClass myclass2;
Myclass myclass = myclass2;         <--- Right?
```

Then `MyClass` object should receive the string and handle it. Unfortunately, from what I read it is only possible to assign the **same data type** value to a custom made class. Is that true or was I mistaken?

This is the code I currently have:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {};
    virtual ~MyClass();
    MyClass& operator = (const MyClass&);
private:
    char* string;
};

MyClass& MyClass::operator= (const MyClass& inc){
    string = inc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyClass myclass = "hello world";
    std::cout << myclass;
}
```

As you can see, I want also to `cout` the object as a string. Basically, I want my custom class to be treated as a string. My search in Google and StackOverflow search engines denied my wish, but is it actually like that or is there a workaround?

Looking forward to hear from you and thank you very much for help in advance!

---

**EDIT:** Rollie fixed the main problem. However, how would we `cout` the string value of the custom object `MyClass`? Is that even possible, since object output is just the memory address of the object being outputted?

Comment: you were mistaken, you can have any type on the right hand side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass myclass = "hello world";` is not an assignment - it's a constructor, and is logically equivilent to `MyClass myclass("hello world");`. Overload both the constructor and assignment operators, and you'll have the behavior you are looking for!

Also some comments:

1) It isn't a great idea to name your member variable `string` - this is the name of a very common STL type

2) setting this variable directly is a time bomb; you aren't copying the *value* of the string, you are just copying the pointer. switch to `std::string` so the copies happen automatically

3) to get `cout` to work properly, see the answer at stackoverflow.com/questions/5508857/how-does-cout-actually-work

Comment: Or just overload the constructor and let the conversion happen for the assignment operator.

Comment: Good point Chris, definitely the easier way to go, but less optimal due to the extra object construction I believe.

Comment: silly me :) thanks. worked too much in other programming languages

Comment: @Rollie, Depends on just what kind of difference it actually makes. I wouldn't go to the extra trouble unless I knew it was worth it.

Comment: By the way, how we would make it to `cout` the string value of `MyClass` object?

Comment: Is that even possible? When we usually `cout` an object, it outputs the memory location of the object.

Comment: see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508857/how-does-cout-actually-work

Comment: @Rollie: Making the class castable to a `const char*` probably isn't a good idea.  A better idea is to overload `operator<<`