# Easy C++ for newbie function of the '<<'

Tags: c++

```
#import <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << 123 <<'\n';
cout <<"$100 recived \n";
cout <<"see you tomorrow \n";

return 0;
}
```

in this C++ program line, i dunno the function of the '<<' here; (i'm a newbie)

for example, an error occurs when i remove the '<<'in the first line

```
#import <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
**cout << 123 '\n';**
cout <<"$100 recived \n";
cout <<"see you tomorrow \n";

return 0;
}
```

i dunno why I need the '<<' please help me :(

Comment: This is one of those things that you begin to understand once you get more fluent in the language. C++ has a steep learning curve like that. Until you reach operator overloading, don't bother understanding this...

Comment: And why are you using `import` (gcc deprecated extension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<` symbol is an [ostream operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) :

> This operator (<<) applied to an output stream is known as insertion operator.

In this case you can think of `<<` as a way of converting a type to something `cout` understands.

First `<< '\n'` converts the character `\n` to data that an output stream understands. `<< 123` does the same for the int `123`.

Together `<< 123 << '\n'` combines each stream into one to be passed to `cout`.

Finally, each different type needs its own `<<` operator to be converted to a stream type for `cout`. When you try and run `<< 123 '\n'` the compiler does not know how to convert an int and a character to a stream at the same time.

Comment: Yes. `operator <<` is always binary in C++.

Comment: "has a left and right hand side".

Comment: @user202729 Which part was wrong?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ **<<** this is output operator. and **>>** this is input operator. So while using **<<** it expected something to be shown in output.

So in your firstline 
       `cout << 123 <<'\n';` second **<<** output operator expected something for displayed, But found nothing, that's why it gives you ERROR.

Comment: It's not called like that. `<<` is either shift left or insertion.

Comment: I am talking about the symbol that C++ uses for its output and input stream. @user202729

Comment: Wrong terms, wrong concepts.

Comment: @NickyC then would you please tell what is **Right terms, right concepts.**

Comment: I don't need to. The right term is told to you right in the very first comment. The right concepts are explained in [how does cout << actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508865/2486888), which this question is a duplicate of.