# Easily initialise an std::list of std::strings?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdstring, stdlist

In C++0x, what I want would be:

```
std::list<std::string> colours = {"red", "blue", "green", "grey", "pink", "violet"};
```

What's the easiest way in standard, non-0x C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
char const *x[] = {"red", "blue", "green", "grey", "pink", "violet"};
std::list<std::string> colours(x, x + sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x));
```

Or you can use the boost libraries and functions like [`list_of("a")("b")...`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of)

Comment: Incidentally, isn't that what C++0x's `std::initializer_list` facility does under the hood, more or less?

Comment: And if you're going to do it a lot: `template<int N, typename T> T *endof(T (&ra)[N]) { return ra + N; }`, which is part of what the C++0x `end` function template does.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/which-c-standard-library-wrapper-functions-do-you-use/2553081#2553081)...

Comment: @Steve: Shouldn't that be `size_t N` instead of `int N`?

Comment: Sometimes I use `ptrdiff_t`. That's what `ptr1 - ptr2` yields (the int operand of `ptr + int` is signed and can be negative). Mostly I see `size_t` being used though which is reasonable too, I think :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: yes, in this case I think `size_t` is best. N is equal to the size of the object (in bytes) divided by something, so `size_t` certainly works. `int` might not be big enough for really big objects, and `ptrdiff_t` might not be able to express the difference between pointers at opposite ends of a really big object as a positive value, so I think probably should not be used as the size in the type of an array.