# Is there a quick way to create a set?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Currently I'm creating a new set like this:

```
    std::set<A> s;
    s.insert(a1);
    s.insert(a2);
    s.insert(a3);
    ...
    s.insert(a10);
```

Is there a way to create `s` in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look into [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), which allows you to write things such as :

```
const std::list<int> primes = boost::assign::list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);
```

Comment: Yes you can! :) (You beat me by 5 seconds...)

Answer (score 22):

```
int myints[]= {10,20,30,40,50};
std::set<int> mySet(myints, myints + 5);
```

Ok, admittedly two lines :)

Comment: Nice, `+1` from me. That's even easier with [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/which-c-standard-library-wrapper-functions-do-you-use/2553081#2553081).

Comment: If it is available, then I prefer `... mySet(myints, myints+_countof(myints)) ...`

Comment: Failing which, you can use `myints + sizeof(myints)/sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 16):

In C++0x the standard defines the [Initializer List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists) as an improvement for this kind of (awkward) construct.

It's much easier now:

```
std::set<int> set = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

All it took was for the standard library to declare the following constructor for set:

```
template <typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
set<Value, Compare, Allocator>::set(std::initializer_list<Value> list);
```

and all our worries were neatly swiped away.

Comment: Note that nowadays, with C++11, you don't even need to declare that constructor.

Comment: @Claudiu: I don't quite understand what you mean, I am afraid.

Comment: I mean you can just do `std::set<int> set = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};` in your code without having to include `template <typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator> set<Value, Compare, Allocator>::set(std::initializer_list<Value> list);`. [Ideone example here](https://ideone.com/wlWCMl).

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes, the set constructor is provided by the set (not by the user), it is mentioned here for exposure only (to expose the feature being used).

Comment: Oh I understand now. I misread it the first few times around. Thanks.

Comment: @Claudiu: No worries, can you think of anything to make this answer clearer? If you misread, I would not be surprised if others did too.

Comment: Maybe rephrase it like "All it took was for the standard library to declare the following constructor for set:" ... "And all our worries were neatly swiped away." Past tense means it's already done, not something I have to do. And the rephrasing makes it impossible to misread "set" as "you" in the first sentence, which is what I did.

Comment: @Claudiu: Good idea! I edited your wording in. Thanks for helping me improve this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at Boost.Assign:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Comment: that's a nice use of overloaded comma operator: +1

Answer (score 5):

If your initial data is in some container `std::some_container<A> a;` which has begin and end iterators, and this are forward iterators or best ones (they just should have operator++ overloaded) then you can make new set this way.

```
std::set<A> s(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a C++0x alternative to Moo-Juice's answer for the case where construction of A is more expensive than for `int`.

```
int myints[]= {10,20,30,40,50};
size_t total(sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));

auto begin(std::make_move_iterator(myints));
auto end(std::make_move_iterator(myints + total));

std::set<int> mySet(begin, end);
```

Comment: @Moo-Juice - yes, but inspired by your original version.