# Sum of different numbers in an array

Tags: c++, loops

I want to have a function that returns the sum of different (non duplicate) values from an array: if I have `{3, 3, 1, 5}`, I want to have sum of `3 + 1 + 5 = 9`.

My attempt was:

```
int sumdiff(int* t, int size){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=size;i++){
        for(int j=i; j<=size;j++){
            if(t[i]!=t[j])
            sum=sum+t[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int t[4]={3, 3, 1, 5};
    cout << sumdiff(t, 4);
}
```

It returns `25` and I think I know why, but I do not know how to improve it. What should I change?

Comment: Please, explain your "why" (you said you think you know why it's not working) in the question. Also, format your code to be more readable.

Comment: (1) You're getting out of the bound of the array; (2) You're comparing the index but not the value of the element for duplication check.

Comment: You have undefined behavior, out of bounds access of the array

Comment: Now i think i am comparing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your loop should be `for (int i=0; i<size;i++)`. Your actual code is accessing out of the bounds of the array.

Then, if you don't want to use STL containers and algorithms (but you should), you can modify your code as follows:

```
int sumdiff(int* t, int size){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++){

        // check if the value was previously added

        bool should_sum = true;

        for(int j=0; should_sum && j<i;j++){
            if(t[i]==t[j])
                should_sum = false;
        }

        if(should_sum)
            sum=sum+t[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int t[4]={3, 3, 1, 5};
    cout << sumdiff(t, 4);
}
```

Comment: One more question why j<i ?

Comment: To go until the element **before** element at index `i`

Answer (score 2):

Put all the items in a set, then count them.

Sets are data structures that hold only one element of each value (i.e., each of their elements is unique; if you try to add the same value more than once, only one instance will be count).

You can take a look in [this interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193430/is-there-a-quick-way-to-create-a-set) about the most elegant way of doing that for ints.

Comment: Maybe expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: I would appreciate.

Comment: Wow, that was super quick, Mike :)

Comment: I have elaborated it a bit, HTH.

Comment: But could it be done in a way similar to what i wanted to do?

Comment: @Mroweczka - *But could it be done in a way similar to what i wanted to do?* --  Think on a higher abstraction.  The goal is to ensure that you write code that doesn't have bugs.  If you google "Sean Parent" and look at his talks on C++, you will see the benefit of eliminating or minimizing writing hand-coded `for` loops.  There is little to no chance of a bug occurring with this answer and other answers that acknowledge usage of `std::set`.

Comment: Thanks, understood. i just wanted to know whether it is possible to go after my initial way of thinking.

Comment: @Mroweczka -- However if you look at your attempt,,it is very inefficient. You have a nested `for` loop over the entire dataset, thus you;re potentially looping n*n times.  In other words, if you have 1,000 numbers, you are looping a million times.  Using a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, the efficiency is improved, since insertion into a set is logarithmic.  So you're not only buying bug free code, you're also buying more efficient code using a set.

Comment: I am aware of that. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

Store your array contents into an [std::unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) first. By doing so, you'd essentially get rid of the duplicates automatically.

Then call [std::accumulate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/) to compute the sum

Answer (score 0):

**wasthishelpful's answer was exactly what i was talking about. I saw his post after i posted mine.

So, you're trying to check the duplicate number using your inner loop. 
However, your outer loop will loop 4 times no matter what which gives you wrong result.
Try,

- Do only checking in inner loop. (use a flag to record if false)
- Do your sum outside of inner loop. (do the sum when flag is true)

Answer (score 0):

Insert array elements into a set and use the [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int t[4] = { 3, 3, 1, 5 };
    std::set<int> mySet(std::begin(t), std::end(t));
    int mySum = std::accumulate(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << mySum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `std::accumulate`, but it iterates over the original elements in the call to `std::accumulate`, and builds the set and keeps a running total as each number in the array is encountered:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int t[4] = { 3, 3, 1, 5 };
    std::set<int> mySet;
    int mySum = std::accumulate(std::begin(t), std::end(t), 0, 
         [&](int n, int n2){return n += mySet.insert(n2).second?n2:0;});
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << mySum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The way it works is that `std::insert()` will return a `pair` tbat determines if the item was inserted. The `second` of the pair is a `bool` that denotes whether the item was inserted in the set.  We only add onto the total if the insertion is successful, otherwise we add `0`.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/rXhb8P)

Comment: `const std::set<int> mySet{std::begin(t), std::end(t)}; const int mySum = std::accumulate(std::begin(t), std::end(t), 0);` seems more natural/simpler.