# Why is the derived class's destructor invoked on a const reference to the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

In [GMan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/which-c-standard-library-wrapper-functions-do-you-use/2553109#2553109), the destructor of the `restore_base` class isn't `virtual`, so I keep wondering how exactly that works. Normally you'd expect the destructor of `restorer_base` to be executed only, after the object goes out of scope, but it seems that the derived `restorer_holder` destructor is really called. Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: This doesn't deserve a question of its own. Ask in the comments under the answer, and @GMan will will update the answer as necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which C++ Standard Library wrapper functions do you use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/which-c-standard-library-wrapper-functions-do-you-use)

Comment: @wilhelmtell No, it absolutely does. The const-ref trick is highly nontrivial and deserves a proper explanation.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Absolutely agree. But somebody with a re of >50K should re-phrase the question so that people understand the real question.

Comment: @Martin: Then tell me how to rephrase it and I'll do so, 'cause I really don't know what else to call it. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard case where you need a virtual destructor is

```
void foo()
{
   scoped_ptr<Base> obj = factory_returns_a_Derived();

   // ... use 'obj' here ...
}
```

And the standard case where you *don't* is

```
void foo()
{
   Derived obj;

   // ... use 'obj' here ...
}
```

GMan's code is doing something a little trickier, that turns out to be equivalent to the second case:

```
void foo()
{
   Base& obj = Derived();

   // ... use 'obj' here ...
}
```

`obj` is a bare reference; normally, it would not trigger destructors at all.  But it's initialized from an anonymous temporary object whose static type -- known to the compiler -- is `Derived`.  When *that object*'s lifetime ends, the compiler will call the `Derived` destructor.  Normally an anonymous temporary object dies at the end of the *expression* that created it, but there's a special case for temporaries initializing a reference: they live till the reference itself dies, which here is the end of the scope.  So you get pseudo-`scoped_ptr` behavior and you don't need a virtual destructor.

**EDIT:** Since this has now come up twice: The reference **does not** have to be `const` for this special rule to apply.  C+98 [class.temporary]/5:

> The second context [in which a temporary object is not destroyed at the end of the
>   full-expression] is when *a reference* is bound to a temporary.  The temporary to which
>   the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object to a subobject of
>   which the temporary is bound persists *for the lifetime of the reference* ...

Emphasis mine. There is no mention of `const` in this language, so the reference does not have to be `const`.

**EDIT 2:** Other rules in the standard prohibit creation of non-const references to temporary objects that are not lvalues. I suspect that at least some temporary objects *are* lvalues, but I don't know for certain.  Regardless, *that does not affect this rule*.  It would still be formally true that non-const references to temporary objects prolong their lifetime *even if* no strictly conforming C++ program could ever create such a reference.  This might seem ridiculous, but you're *supposed* to read standardese this literally and pedantically.  Every word counts, every word that isn't there counts.

Comment: slightly clarified the kind of reference that prolongs the life of a temporary, hope you don't mind...

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense now! :) So with C++0x, would one use rvalue reference instead of the const reference?

Comment: @Eugen Thanks ... but I was looking at the standard (12.2p5 [class.temporary]) and I don't see anything in there about the reference having to be `const`, could you clarify where you got the restriction?  @Xeo I don't really understand rvalue references, I have no idea if they'd be appropriate in this case.

Comment: You're totally right, I was reading the `Derived()` call wrong (as a function call and thinking of this http://herbsutter.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!2D4327CC297151BB!378.entry ). Rolled back my unnecessary & incorrect modification.

Comment: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Base&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Derived’`   I'm getting this with g++ 4.6.3 and `-std=c++98`.  I was always convinced the `const` was necessary.  I feel very confused :P   http://ideone.com/rIDf4t

Comment: [The reference does have to be `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6967927/509868) because of another text in the Standard somewhere. I guess `const` was not mentioned in C98 [class.temporary]/5 just to prevent the text from being ugly. I guess the "reference does not have to be const" part comes from Visual Studio implementing a language extension that behaves that way.

Comment: @anatolyg What I'm about to say may sound like a ridiculous level of pedanticism, but it is in fact the *necessary* level of pedanticism with which to read standardese. You've cited a rule that means "you can't create a non-const reference to a non-lvalue." That *does not mean* a non-const reference to a temporary doesn't prolong the lifetime of the temporary. It just means the obvious way to create such a reference doesn't work. If you somehow *do* create such a reference, the standard requires it to prolong the lifetime of the temporary.