# "warning C4350: behavior change" when including <string> and no precompiled header

Tags: warnings, visual-studio-2012, precompiled-headers

Warning C4350 says "A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue".  I think since C4350 is off by default I haven't found much out there on it.  I have read this post and it makes sense: 
[Non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967927/non-const-reference-may-only-be-bound-to-an-lvalue)

Anyway, I'm asking about it because I'm trying to update VS2008 VC++ projects to VS2012.  When I do I get hundreds of C4350 warnings which I have turned on for some legacy reason (that admittedly may need to be reassessed).  I have whittled it down to this simple bit of code that can reproduce the warning, but only if I have precompiled headers turned off:

```
#pragma warning(default:4350)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

If I turn precomiled headers on I get no warning.  I also can't get it to happen in VS2008.

Is this a Visual Studio 2012 bug in std:string?  Why does the precompiled header change the behavior?  How do I fix the problem, as opposed to just ignoring the warning?  Thanks!

The warning is (sorry for the poor formatting, it was the best I could figure):

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(689): warning C4350: behavior change: 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc(const std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> &) throw()' called instead of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc>(_Other &) throw()'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(838) : see declaration of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(850) : see declaration of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(688) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>::_Getal(void) const'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator,

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(898) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>::_Getal(void) const' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator,

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(700) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdexcept(31) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Elem=char,

1>              _Traits=std::char_traits,

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(689): warning C4350: behavior change: 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc(const std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> &) throw()' called instead of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc>(_Other &) throw()'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(838) : see declaration of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(850) : see declaration of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::_Wrap_alloc'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

1>          A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(688) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>::_Getal(void) const'

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator,

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(898) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc> std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>::_Getal(void) const' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator,

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(700) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_String_alloc<_Al_has_storage,_Alloc_types>' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Al_has_storage=false,

1>              _Alloc_types=std::_String_base_types>

1>          ]

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(689) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' being compiled

1>          with

1>          [

1>              _Elem=wchar_t,

1>              _Traits=std::char_traits,

1>              _Alloc=std::allocator

1>          ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft answered my question here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767960/warning-c4350-behavior-change-when-including-string-and-no-precompiled-header

**Summary:**

*Is this a Visual Studio 2012 bug in std:string?* 
-They don't count it as a bug if if cleanly builds at warning level 4, which excludes this warning

*Why does the precompiled header change the behavior?*
-The compiler ignores everything that comes before a precompiled header, which in this case was my pragma statement that was enabling the warning.  Enabling precompiled headers in the property settings caused the pragma to be ignored.  Who knew?

*How do I fix the problem, as opposed to just ignoring the warning?*
-No fix it would seem, just ignore the warning