# Why am I getting an error, "non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::basic_string<char>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const char [4]'"

Tags: c++, templates, constants, lvalue

I had a queue and originally worked with strings and now I added templates to it so that if I decide to add int doubles, etc, it would still work. When using strings to add to my queue, I get an error where it says "non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::basic_string<char>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const char [4]'". Does this mean it is reading the type string as type char?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
struct Node {
  Type data;
  Node<Type>* nextNode;
  Node(Type& data) : data(data), nextNode(nullptr) {}
};

template <class Type>
class Queue {
  public:
  Node<Type>* head;
  Node<Type>* tail;

  Queue() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}

  ~Queue(){
    while (!isEmpty()){
      remove();
    }
  }

  bool isEmpty() {
   return head == nullptr;
  }

  void add(Type &data){
    Node<Type>* newNode = new Node<Type>(data);
    if (isEmpty()){
      head = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    } else {
      Node<Type>* temp = tail;
      temp->nextNode = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }
  }

  void remove(){
    if (isEmpty()){
      std::cout << "Not able to remove from empty queue.";
      return;
    }
    Node<Type>* temp = head;
    head = head->nextNode;
    delete temp;
  }

  Type peek(){
    if (isEmpty()){
      cout << "Queue is empty. ";
      return Type();
    }
    return head->data;
  }

};

template <class Type>
ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Queue<Type> &s){
  Node<Type>* temp = s.head;
  while (temp != nullptr) {
    out << s.head->data << " ";
    temp = temp->nextNode;
  }
  return out;
}

void fillQueue(Queue<string> &queue) {
  queue.add("one");
  queue.add("two");
  queue.add("three");
  queue.add("four");
  cout << queue << endl;
}

void check(string name, const string shouldBe, string currentlyIs) {
  if (shouldBe == currentlyIs) {
    cout << name << ": Passed " << endl;
  } else {
    cout << name << ": Failed, value should be " << shouldBe
         << " but is returning " << currentlyIs << endl;
  }
}

void check(string name, bool shouldBe, bool currentlyIs) {
  if (shouldBe == currentlyIs) {
    cout << name << ": Passed " << endl;
  } else {
    cout << name << ": Failed, value should be " << shouldBe
         << " but is returning " << currentlyIs << endl;
  }
}

void testIsEmpty() {
  Queue<string> queue;
  check("1. Checking Empty Queue", queue.isEmpty(), true);
  queue.add("one");
  queue.remove();
  check("2. Checking Recently Empty Queue", queue.isEmpty(), true);
}

void checkQueueOrder() {
  Queue<string> queue;
  fillQueue(queue);
  string txt = "one";
  check("3. Check Front: ", queue.peek(), txt);
  queue.remove();
  txt = "two";
  check("4. Check Second: ", queue.peek(), txt);
}


int main() {
  testIsEmpty();
  checkQueueOrder();
}
```

These are the lines where I get these errors:

```
void fillQueue(Queue<string> &queue) {
  queue.add("one");
  queue.add("two");
  queue.add("three");
  queue.add("four");
  cout << queue << endl;
}
```

and this function

```
  void add(Type &data){
    Node<Type>* newNode = new Node<Type>(data);
    if (isEmpty()){
      head = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    } else {
      Node<Type>* temp = tail;
      temp->nextNode = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }
  }
```

I get a note: "note: passing argument to parameter 'data' here void add(Type &data){"

```
I tried using variables:
```

```
void fillQueue(Queue<string> &queue) {
string x = "one"
queue.add(x);
queue.add("two");//etc etc.
queue.add("three");
queue.add("four");
cout << queue << endl;
}
```

I also tried using type int as well and similar error pops up. (I changed code to take ints instead of strings)

```
void fillQueue(Queue<int> &queue) {
  queue.add(1);
  queue.add(2);
  queue.add(3);
  queue.add("4);
  cout << queue << endl;
}
```

Comment: `Type &data` is `std::string &data` and you're passing a string literal as an argument when you wrote `queue.add("one")` . Basically, the argument `"one"` cannot bind to `std::string&`

Comment: [Since a string literal is considered an lvalue, why must the binding lvalue reference be const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869719/since-a-string-literal-is-considered-an-lvalue-why-must-the-binding-lvalue-refe)

Comment: Please read about the [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `const char [4]` type is from your string literal `"two"` -- that is four bytes (including the string's null-terminator) of non-modifiable memory.

The error here is that your member function `add(Type&)` is receiving a *lvalue* reference, which essentially means something that is modifiable (*e.g.* some non-const variable belonging to the caller). But you're not allowed to change a string literal at runtime. The compiler cannot convert it that into a temporary `std::string` and then bind *that* to the reference because the language doesn't allow it.

To easily fix the problem, you should make the reference `const`. That will allow the compiler to automatically convert it to a temporary `std::string` and bind that to the reference:

```
void add(const Type &data)
{
    // ...
}
```

As a general rule, if a function does not need to modify the data being referenced, then you should make it const. That includes your `Node` class template. For example:

```
template <class Type>
struct Node {
  Type data;
  Node<Type>* nextNode;
  Node(const Type& data) : data(data), nextNode(nullptr) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that when you wrote `queue.add("one")`, you're passing a string literal of type `const char [4]` as an argument to `Queue<string>::add(std::string&)`  but the parameter of that member function is of type `std::string&` which cannot be bound to the argument `"add"` because a string literal is non-modifiable(note the `const` in `const char[4]`).

---

##### Solution

The solution is to add a **low-level const** to the parameter as shown below:

```
//-------vvvvv---------------->added const here
void add(const Type &data);
```

**Additionally**, for the program to compile, you'll also need to add `const` in the constructor parameter of `Node` as shown below:

```
//---vvvvv------------------>added const here
Node(const Type& data)
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Mh4GaqEo)