# count specific number of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, count

For example, if I have an array of 5 inputted elements, how would I count how many times a specific value was entered if that value has already been established in a variable.

```
INPUT:
4
4
4
1
2
```

If `click` is defined as `4` then how would I count how many times `click` is used in the array?
Hopefully that makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it with C style arrays.

```
int i;
int count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; ++i)
{
    if(array[i] == click)
        ++count;
}
```

ARRAYSIZE is the size of your statically allocated array, `array` your array variable and click the value you are looking for. In `count` the count of the variable is saved.

Answer (score 15):

As you've tagged your question as C++, here is a proper C++ answer, using STL.

```
int num = std::count(&array[0], &array[5], click);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: Hm. Is `&array[5]` actually valid? I know that deferencing and using address-of can cause undefined behaviour (as in, `&(*(array + 5))`).

Comment: @Oli: Why don't you use `array+5` instead of `&array[5]`?  i.e ... `int num = std::count(array, array+5, click);`

Comment: Yes, &array[5] should be valid for a 5-element array. For an array of size N there are elements numbered 0 to N-1 but the address of element N is a valid address, even although accessing that element gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AAT: If *the address of element N is a valid address*, then why accessing that element gives undefined behavior? Any explanation for that?

Comment: @Konrad: It's certainly idiomatic.  The C99 standard quote (I don't have the C++ standard to hand) is: "*If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.*" (6.5.6/8)  In this context, I don't think it's evaluated.

Comment: @Nawaz: it might, for instance, be a memory location being used by another variable. Or it might not. The C++ standard just guarantees that you can do pointer arithmetic between any 2 array elements **and** the notional element which is just off the end of the array.

Comment: @Oli: The address operator `&` is an unary operator, that means, according to the C99 quotation which you quoted, `&array[5]` invokes undefined-behavior. Also, `&array[5]` is equivalent to `&(*(array+5))` which uses another unary operator `*`.

Comment: @AAT I know this, but it’s not relevant here: Oli isn’t merely addressing the element, he’s dereferencing it using `[]`. I know for a fact that my code (`&*(a + 5)`) has caused the debugger of at least one recent (post 6.0) version of VC++ to complain about invalid access. So whether or not it’s legal, it doesn’t always work. Since it was my impression that `a[b]` for C arrays is strictly equivalent to `*(a + b)`, this would mean that Oli’s code would exhibit the same problem.

Comment: @konrad: I believe that the C++ committee wants this, and your example to be allowed.  If you follow the link, you'll find a good bit of discussion.  Of note is where they say that "p=0; *p;" is only an error if there is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232.  Of course, the issue is still open so the standard doesn't yet clearly state this.

Comment: @AAT: arithmetic on the pointer doesn't invoke undefined-behavior, but dereferencing it does.

Comment: I agree with Konrad, while doing `array + 5` is perfectly fine, doing `array[5]` is not, even if it is only to apply the address-of operator to obtain the equivalent. It will in most cases be optimized away by the compiler (`&*(array+5)` will be converted to `array+5`) by the compiler yielding a somehow expected undefined behavior, but it is still undefined behavior. For another example, if the array contained an user defined type `T`, instead of `int`s, it could well overload `T::operator&` over a region of memory that is not of a `T`. The standard does not make exceptions here, and it is UB.

Comment: @David: The last point regarding user-defined type and overloaded `T::operator &` is good.

Comment: @David (and others claiming UB):  At least according to the people actually writing the standard, they do not feel that this is definitely UB (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232).  The important line being:  "We agreed that the approach in the standard seems okay: p = 0; *p; is not inherently an error."

Comment: I think when a bunch of high-rep SO users reading the standard and ongoing debates in the std committee can't agree whether a certain technique is actually valid, there's a good chance the code would be better off not using said technique. (Even if it should be safe, isn't it likely some compiler writers got that wrong?)

Comment: Oh, and here's a shameless plug: Use [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/2553081#2553081). They are doing it right for sure, and you can forget about the issue once and for all. (I do believe C++11 will have `std::begin()`/`std::end()` out of the box, BTW.)

Comment: @Konrad, @Nawaz, @AAT, @David, @sbi: To formalise this discussion, I've created a question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975586/is-arrayarray-length-valid-c-or-c.  Oh, no!  Delete!  That's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158, which appears to suggest that it *is* valid.

Comment: @Oli - thanks for finding that other question, let's all go there and read it instead of extending the discussion here! @Konrad, @Nawaz -- &array[5] is most certainly **not** something I would advocate doing, but I think it is clearly legal. (@sbi -- I pretty much agree with your take on it.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/).

Something like this (sorry I'm out of practice with C++):

```
#include <algorithm>

void someFunction() {
    int input[5];
    // initialize input with some values
    int num = std::count(&input[0], &input[5], 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't sorted, then linear search is your only choice.