# C++ Determine the type of a variable and use it within sizeof()

Tags: c++, types, sizeof, typeof, typeid

I would like to write a macro in c++ which would give the value 0 to every element of a table. For instance, having declared `i` thus: `int i[10];`, the macro `fill_with_zeros(i)` would produce this effect:

`i[0] = 0;`

`i[1] = 0;` and so on.

This is its code:

```
#define fill_with_zeros(xyz) \
    for(int l = 0 ; l < sizeof(xyz) / sizeof(int) ; l++) \
        xyz[l] = 0;
```

The problem is that I want it to work with tables of multiple types: char, int, double etc. And for this, I need a function that would determine the type of `xyz`, so that instead of `sizeof(int)` I could use something like `sizeof(typeof(xyz))`.

Similar threads exist but people usually want to print the type name whereas I need to use the name within sizeof(). Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a question. Why not `int i[10] = { 0 };` ? Or even `memset` ?

Comment: @vpprof: While there are times and places where a macro is appropriate, this is not one of them. Especially since solutions like `memset()` does what you want but better. It's best to avoid using macros in C++ unless they are really needed.

Comment: That's true, you can't do anything smarter (and faster for tables) than memset. Also when dealing with heap allocated tables you still need to know the exact size as sizeof won't help you.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you think you need a macro for that? This should work:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
template< typename T, std::size_t sz >
inline void init(T (&array)[sz])
{
  std::fill( array, array+sz, T() );
}
```

I'd expect my std lib implementation to optimize `std::fill()` to call `std::memset()` (or something similar) on its own if `T` allows it.

Note that this does not actually zero the elements, but uses a default-constructed object for initialization. This achieves the same for all types that can be zeroed, plus works with many types that cannot.

Comment: very good for brain compiled, personally I find the brain compiler to be a little slow sometimes and has erroneous parsing methods :P

Comment: _Much_ better solution than `memset`, which is almost always the wrong answer, stomping all over our nice abstractions...  I think you mean `sz` instead of `idx` in your call.  Of course, this begs the question "why not use a `std::vector` and be done with it"

Comment: @Jesus: To be fair, the code is an adapted version of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/2553081#2553081). But you know as it is, such seemingly simple and innocent adaptations usually introduce a glaringly obvious error which only the one who changed the code cannot see. And Nemo proved that to be true once again...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [`memset(xyz, 0, sizeof(xyz));`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/)?

All-bits 0 = zero for all built-in types (integer and float).

Comment: What if `xyz` is an array of `double`? TTBOMK it's not guaranteed that you can legally zero a floating point value.

Answer (score 2):

The length of an array can be determined as `sizeof(xyz) / sizeof(xyz[0])`. However, there are already `ZeroMemory` and `memset` functions that do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define fill_with_zeroes(arr) \
    for (int l = 0; l < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); l++) \
        arr[l] = 0;
```

Alternatively just call `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));`

I would suggest using memset instead or int i[10] = { 0 };

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `std::memset` from `<cstring>`?  This is what it was designed for and will in most cases work a lot faster.

```
int i[10];
memset (i, 0, sizeof (i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `memset` as others have suggested, but if you really want to go the macro route:

```
#define fill_with_zeros(xyz) \
for(size_t l = 0 ; l < sizeof(xyz) / sizeof(xyz[0]) ; l++) \
    xyz[l] = 0;
```